# XMLHTTPRequest - The currentPage parameter not updated while form submit without refreshing

Tags: javascript, jsp, xmlhttprequest

I have a function like below:

```
function submitNextPageRequest() {
            createRequest();
            request.open("POST", "getFilteredData?  pageIndex=${currentPage+1}&channelName=${channelName}&modelType=${modelType}&queryparam=${queryparam}",true);
            request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
            request.onreadystatechange = showResults;
            request.send();
        }
```

I call this function in `onclick` way from the button.

```
<button type="button" id="nextBtn" name="nextBtn" onclick="submitNextPageRequest()">Next</button>
```

Application behaviour:

Initially the page will be loaded with 10 results page.

After I click next button, the pageIndex param will be passed as 2. This param will be retrieved in servlet and I will load send next 10 results to JSP based on pageIndex param.
While sending to JSP, I am setting pageIndex in the request attribute to 2. So, when I click Next the pageIndex will become 3.

From page2, I click Next button. But the pageIndex remains as 2.

Can anyone please help me on this issue. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Refernce, I am appending these functions also:  function showResults() {
  if (request.readyState == 4) {
   if (request.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = request.responseText;
   }
  }
 }
 function createRequest() {
  try {
   request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (noXMLHttpRequestException) {
   try {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
   } catch (noMsxml2XMLHTTPException) {
    try {
     request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (noMicrosoftXMLHTTPException) {
     request = false;
    }
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Is there any way that I can increment pageIndex by 1 whenever I click Next Button in JSP..?